# What does "pillow-plumping romance with the press" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across the phrase “pillow-plumping romance with the press” in Maureen Dowd’s article titled “Liability Index” in *New York Times* August 11 issue. It reads:

> The president survived a “raised by wolves” upbringing, as Michelle has called it. He retained the monastic skills that sustained him through the solitude of his years in New York. His “winning smile,” as Jonathan Alter wrote in “The Promise,” “obscured a layer of self-protective ice.” His staffers respect him, but he doesn’t inspire the kind of adoration that the Bush presidents got. And the *pillow-plumping romance with the press* is over.

All three online dictionaries of Cambridge, Oxford, and  Merriam-Webster I use to consult with carry *pillow talk*, but none of them registers *pillow-plumping*.

OALD simply defines *plump* “having a soft, round body” as adjective, and “to make sth larger, softer and rounder” as transitive verb.

I assume *pillow-plumping romance* means “close and friendly relationship” with press from the context, but am not sure.

What does *pillow-plumping* mean? Is it very popular word?

Can I say “Sonny’s pillow-plumping romance with Hollywood is over”, or “Tom had a pillow-plumping romance (or relationship) with the shop clerk.”?

Comment: I would only add that "pillow plumping" is something a couple might do after sex so that they could more easily put the pillows under their chins and thus facilitate an intimate conversation, face to face. It describes a level of infatuation common to early-stage romances.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's nowhere near a "standard idiom", so strictly thinking I think this question might be off-topic (it's effectively literary criticism/interpretation).

Obama's *romance* is just an alternative to [honeymoon [with the press]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22run%20like%20a%20gazelle%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22honeymoon%20with%20the%20press%22&oq=%22honeymoon%20with%20the%20press%22&gs_l=serp.3...6359.14257.8.14807.23.23.0.0.0.0.115.1201.20j2.23.0.ckwcph..0.0...1.0EpjvoF7H84&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=6e8542fb6fd51cb5&biw=1353&bih=886) - a common metaphor attaching to public figures newly risen to the attention of the media.

Literally, *pillow-plumping* is just beating and fluffing up a pillow to make it more comfortable. When conjoined with the metaphoric *press romance*, it emphasises how the press have made his early years as president comfortable/easy. Ensuring her man has a nice soft place (breast, pillow) to lay his head is something an adoring lover might do in the first flush of new romance.

This "soft pillow" metaphor harks back to Obama's *"monastic skills"* as mentioned earlier in the passage. By cliched convention (and to some extent, historical fact), monks live ascetic/abstinent existences, in which context beds of nails, and *hard stone pillows*, are common images.

TL;DR: *pillow-plumping* here means *indulgent and comforting*.

Comment: I imagined ‘close and friendly relationship of Obama with the press’ by the phrase, ‘pillow-plumping romance with the press,’ which I don’t think is too far from your definition, ‘the President’s honeymoon’ with the press. It isn’t difficult to infer that way from the context. But it’s hard for foreign English learners to guess offhand what ‘pillow-plumping romance’ is when shown alone, I mean without the context, particularly when no dictionary carries this word.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: As I write, David's answer has as many upvotes as mine, but I don't think there's even the slightest allusion to *romantic **novels** being read in bed* in your extract. I don't know what percentage of voters are native speakers, but I doubt it makes much difference anyway. With Dowd's obscure "metaphoric coinages", not everyone understands exactly what she's getting at - and sometimes different alternatives are possible, whether or not she intends them. I expect I've said before that you probably shouldn't attempt to copy her somewhat quirky style.

Comment: I can't emphasize enough the veracity of FumbleFingers answer, and especially the comment he made subsequently. Sorry, I'm trying to say ***HE IS CORRECT*** The style of prose used by Dowd is not standard usage, by which I mean this: She chose to use a style of writing that is atypical for journalism and political reporting. It isn't wrong or bad. Yoichi, to help clarify my point, I would compare this to an earlier question you asked, regarding another U.S. political candidate.

Comment: @Feral Oink: Quite. I'm pretty sure I've been critical of Dowd's style here in the past, but really it's just that Yoichi often adds a "supplementary question" along the lines of *"Can I reasonably use (or even, *extend*) the unusual usage being asked about?"*. To which my knee-jerk reaction is invariably *"Only if you're happy for your prose style to be seen as 'quirky'"*. But even though *her particular usages* are often peculiar to her, I'm not so sure the *general* style is "atypical" of political columnists in middle-class newspapers/magazines.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I found the question. It was this one http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49575/can-i-say-what-you-are-saying-is-pants-on-fire-when-i-dont-trust-what-my-e While it is of a political nature, it is not quite the same situation as this question.

Comment: ...in the UK, people like [Barbara Amiel, Russell Brand, Keith Waterhouse, Polly Toynbee, Simon Heffer, A. A. Gill, etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_newspaper_columnists) (not necessarily exclusively or even primarily ***political** columnists*) commonly adopt such flowery, "pseudo-erudite" styles. Sometimes, I suspect, because it adds a potential touch of light-heartedness that might get them off the hook in a libel case where they can say *"It was obviously written with tongue-in-cheek, m'lud!"*. Besides, the readers presumably like it, or they'd not buy the publications.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There is a risk in using this "pseudo-erudite", or over-wrought style, even for those for whom English is a first (or only) language. There is a good chance of being perceived as silly, and distinctly un-funny. I know this to be true, because I indulge in such style of writing myself sometimes. That is why I hesitate to recommend emulating Dowd's style. If a native speaker who has an idiomatic comprehension of a language can't carry this off consistently,  not even Dowd is successful every time, then it is inadvisable for others to do so, and expect a positive outcome.

Comment: @Feral: That is *exactly* the point. Dowd's style may not always work for everyone, and she's obviously a *very* competent speaker/writer. Not a good "model" for Yoichi, even though for a non-native speaker he is imho unusually good at picking up on the finer points of idiomatic/metaphoric usages in "carefully-written" English (that's why he usually only asks about really obscure ones! :)

Comment: @FumbleFinger. As a non-native English speaker who’ve been to but never lived in English speaking countries, I can’t judge whether Maureen Dawd is a good writer or not. But I can tell her style of writing is very different from those of other authors I see in many newspapers. It is always a nerve-racking exercise for me to decode the meaning of her ‘quirky’ expressions when I read NYT. I never dreamed of imitating her style in writing. But it is true that her writings keep me alert with a wide variety of expressions and diverse usages of English language ,

Comment: Continued -and provide me with the rich lode for posting questions in EL&U that have turned out to be many up-votes.

Answer (score 9):

My understanding is that this is all about how, when you're reading a really good book in bed, you might thump your pillow to make it fatter, so that you can sit up in bed more comfortably.  Thumping your pillow this way is called "plumping", because it makes your pillow plumper.  So a "pillow-plumping" romance would be a romance novel that you would read in bed; more particularly, it's a gripping enough book that you would "plump up" your pillow and read it, in preference to switching off the light and going to sleep.

In the case of Obama, it's kind of a metaphor; the American people were eager to read about Obama, and everything he did that was reported favourably by the press.  Now, they're not so eager any more - the pillow plumping has finished.

As worded in the *Times* article, *pillow-plumping romance* probably refers to the act of pillow plumping – how one lover might plump the pillow for the other, suggesting the great care, deference, attention, and infatuation that often accompany the early stages of a new romantic relationship. In other words, suggesting that the *pillow-plumping romance is over* is another way of saying that the (metaphorical) *honeymoon is over*.

Comment: I would think that _pillow-plumping romance_ refers to how one lover might plump the pillow for the other, suggesting the great care, deference, attention, and infatuation that often accompany the early stages of a new romantic relationship. In other words, suggesting that the _pillow-plumping romance is over_ is another way of saying that the (metaphorical) _honeymoon is over_.

Comment: @David Wallace.I feel difficulty to interpret ‘the pillow-plumping romance with the press is over’ as ‘the page-turner novel with the press is over,’ as your suggest, because “the pillow-plumping novel’ doesn’t seem to sit well with ‘the press.’

Comment: @J.R. I'm going to delete this answer, because I've had time to think about it some more, and I think I got it a bit wrong (despite the three upvotes).  I think FumbleFingers' answer is very good; and that your comment here would make an even better answer.  I will leave this answer here for long enough for you to cut and paste your comment into an answer of your own.  Once you've done that, I will delete it.

Comment: I don't see any need to delete your answer, which has some very good points. Instead of moving my comment to an answer, I've simply appended it to yours. I hope you don't mind us working as a team here; after all, my comment was inspired by your answer, not conjured in a vacuum.

Comment: Umm, OK, but it still seems to me like yours is a completely different answer from mine.  That is, I say that the pillow-plumping is to prop myself up to read a book; and you say that it's a gesture of caring for one's lover.  I really think that your answer would be better off as an independent entity.

Comment: _Thumping your pillow this way is called "plumping", because it makes your pillow plumper._ That would be a necessary introduction to my comment, so I'd have to borrow from you. Not only that, context is everything. Some folks might call _50 Shades of Grey_ a "pillow-plumping romance;" I think it's worth mentioning that the phrase could be used in that way, too. I'd hate to see your answer deleted, especially since you have _seven_ upvotes now, up from the three you had when you made your comment last night.

Comment: Damn, I wish people would stop upvoting me!  OK, let's leave it as it is.  I'm sure anyone who is interested enough in this particular answer will read the comments here, and realise that your parts of it are to be taken more seriously than my parts are.

Comment: ＠David Wallace. Please don’t delete your answer. Your answer is valuable in depicting how intimacy is demonstrated by pillow-plumping exercise between couples. You concluded your answer by saying ‘the pillow-plumping romance is over is another way of saying that the honeymoon is over’ – the notion most of answerers agree with. I congratulate you for gaining 8 votes that support your way of interpretation.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - The part of my answer that you are enjoying so much was written by J.R., not by me.  I wanted to encourage him/her to post that particular bit under his/her own name, not under mine.  I failed.

Comment: @David Walles. Regardless who wrote or suggested the conclusive line, it’s in your answer and you have ownership of your entire answer. You needn’t to be shy, and you got 8 up-voters behind you who don’t care which part were yours and other’s at all. Well, let’s finish talk on ‘copyright’ issue around here.

Comment: I don't like to seem negative, but apart from the fanciful/erroneous "romantic novels" bit, I can't see anything in this answer that wasn't covered by mine. Without the *"monastic"* and *"press honeymoon"* allusions that aren't even mentioned here, Dowd's extended metaphoric usage is effectively incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve never heard *pillow-plumping* before, but it sounds like something they might do for you at a cosy little bed-and-breakfast, fluffing your pillow for you in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

A "pillow plumping" romance is a "hot and heavy" romance.

Thinking of two teenagers in bed "making out," possibly for the first time, heads banging (pun intended) on pillows, thereby making them "plumper."